# What are potential obstacles when switching from XML to SQLite Core Data store?

Tags: cocoa, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

For example, when using `entity.name` in `NSPredicate`, I needed to change setFetchPredicate to setFilterPredicate, the 1st one was working just fine with XML store, SQLite required 2nd one.

I found: [this message](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/May/msg00209.html) but couldn't find anything related in the list archive.

Is there any list with all valid `NSPredicate` statements?

When garbage collection can cause troubles?

Answer (score 1):

See the section titled "[Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW3)" of the Core Data Programming Guide for SQLite-specific limitations.

I'm not aware of any Core-Data-specific limitations in a Garbage-Collection-enabled environment - the reference in the e-mail you posted is news to me. A quick Google search revealed [this thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/229108-core-data-garbage-collection-and-sql-store.html) and it's the first I'm hearing of this issue. I certainly never encountered it despite having a similar setup in a compute-intensive app that used Core Data + SQLite store type.

You'll need to be a lot more specific about your first question, however. I'm not sure what you mean.